# Image upload/download using aws lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a lambda function which accepts an image as multipart object, then does some processing and uploads it to s3 bucket and provides some response back to the user.

I have found some examples how to proceed however, i do not understand do i have to create two lambda functions and upload separate jars or it can be done differently.

So far i have service that parses multipart and uploads to s3 , my question is how to approach using aws lambdas, thank you guys

```
public String uploadFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        String fileUrl = "";
        try {
            File file = convertMultiPartToFile(multipartFile);
            String fileName = generateFileName(multipartFile);
            fileUrl = endpointUrl + "/" + bucketName + "/" + fileName;
            uploadFileTos3bucket(fileName, file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return fileUrl;
    }

    private File convertMultiPartToFile(MultipartFile file){
        File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
            fos.write(file.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return convFile;
    }

    private String generateFileName(MultipartFile multiPart) {
        return new Date().getTime() + "-" + multiPart.getOriginalFilename().replace(" ", "_");
    }

    private void uploadFileTos3bucket(String fileName, File file) {
        s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, file)
                .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you can simply use one lambda function, which should be integrated with an api gateway endpoint. So the user can invoke the endpoint (post) with the file that needs to be uploaded into S3 and then from the lambda function you can do the rest ( processing + uploading to s3) and then return some response back to the user.

[This](https://medium.com/think-serverless/image-upload-and-retrieval-from-s3-using-aws-api-gateway-and-lambda-b4c2961e8d1) could be a starting point.

to get the s3 URL of your uploaded file:

```
s3Client.getUrl("your_bucket_name", "your_file_key").toExternalForm();
```

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) is another example to resize the images in S3 using Lambda. It's JS code though and uses only one Lambda function.

Comment: Thank you, lets say i want to also have additional method that gets links for all uploaded images and send them back to the ui, do i need two lambdas in such case or still can proceed with a single one

Comment: you can do it within the same lambda itself; after the putObject call is successful, you can claim the url by placing the above line of code which i have posted and then simply return it as a response.

Comment: alright thank you, now i need to figure out how to get the list of links, but  yeh  all i want to do is to upload file and have a get method that retrieves all links of uploaded images.

Comment: no problem, any time. Yeah in that case, you might've to put those s3 urls into a HashMap or even a list and then return it as a whole in the response, after you've uploaded each file.

Comment: yeh its an option but also it would be better to be able to trigger it somehow  , otherwise i will keep returning it without the need so i would like to return the whole list on demand

Comment: yeah that's true; each lambda invocation comes with a cost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224419/discussion-between-prozorov-and-kulasangar).